# Spyder 3 Errors and UI Loading Incorrectly

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda, spyder

Having issues loading Spyder 3 from Anaconda Navigator. At first it was giving me an error related to the Spyder 3 icon set not loading and it would revert to Spyder 2. From there it would not launch at all. By forcing it from the terminal using 'show-console' I was able to bring up the editor, however the icon set is now cut off at the top and I cannot access any of the drop down menus:
[Missing Drop Downs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uth5J.jpg)

After resetting Spyder to defaults multiple times in different environments including root and then reinstalling Anaconda I was eventually able to get this error message from the Spyder internal console:

> > > Spyder Internal Console
> > >
> > > This console is used to report application
> > >       internal errors and to inspect Spyder
> > >       internals with the following commands:
> > >         spy.app, spy.window, dir(spy)
> > >
> > > Please don't use it to run your code
> > >
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Users\Chapin23\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 528, in get
> > >           value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
> > >       KeyError: 'banner'
> > >
> > > During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> > >
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Users\Chapin23\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\base_frontend_mixin.py", line 163, in _dispatch
> > >           handler(msg)
> > >         File "C:\Users\Chapin23\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\jupyter_widget.py", line 296, in _handle_kernel_info_reply
> > >           super(JupyterWidget, self)._started_channels()
> > >         File "C:\Users\Chapin23\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\frontend_widget.py", line 615, in _started_channels
> > >           self.reset(clear=True)
> > >         File "C:\Users\Chapin23\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\frontend_widget.py", line 659, in reset
> > >           self._append_plain_text(self.banner)
> > >         File "C:\Users\Chapin23\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 556, in **get**
> > >           return self.get(obj, cls)
> > >         File "C:\Users\Chapin23\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 535, in get
> > >           value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
> > >         File "C:\Users\Chapin23\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\shell.py", line 250, in _banner_default
> > >           return self.long_banner()
> > >         File "C:\Users\Chapin23\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\shell.py", line 86, in long_banner
> > >           from IPython.core.usage import quick_guide
> > >       ImportError: cannot import name 'quick_guide'

Anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: spyder version??

Comment: Happening with all 3.x.x versions.